# solving differential equations in Excel

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How to solve a differential equation using Euler's Method in Excel? A rocket has a mass of 2000 kg of which 1500 kg is fuel. It burns the fuel at the rate of 25 kg/s and develops a thrust of 5000 N. Construct a worksheet to show how the velocity varies with time.  Any ideas about the y0 value?

Comment: Sounds like the initial mass is 2000 and the initial velocity is 0. The two satisfy a first order system of equations (which you could actually solve explicitly...)

Comment: Dont you mean $50000 N$? Because with $5000N$ the rocket does not develop enough thrust to start. (And with $50000 N$ you also get a nice peak-height of $99km$ at $179s$)

Answer (score 2):

Make one column with $t_n$ values, and one with $v_n$ values.

Fill the first column with increments the size of $h$, adding on from the $t_0$ value.

For the $v_n$ values, after adding the initial $v_0$ value, use this:

$$
v_{n+1}=v_n+h(\frac{dv}{dt})
$$

Of course, you need to convert it into a form that Excel understands, which depends on what columns you are using and the nature of your excel document.

Answer (score 0):

Column A: $\delta t$ or $h$ depending on your preference (heading in A1)

Initial value: try 0.1 in A2

Column B: Time (heading in B1)

Initial value: 0 (in B2)

Formula (in B3): "=B2+A$2"

Column C: Mass (heading in C1)

Initial value: 2000 (in C2)

Formula (in C3): =MAX(C2-25*A$2,500)

This reduces the mass by 25 kg per second, but stops the mass from going below 500kg (mass with no fuel)

Column D: Thrust (heading in D1)

Initial value: 5000 (in D2)

Formula (in D3): "=IF(C3>500,5000,0)"

This checks that there is still fuel.

Column E: Acceleration (heading in E1)

Formula (in E2): "=D2/C2"

Column F: Velocity (heading in F1)

Initial value (in F2): 0

Formula (in F3):"=F2+A$2*E2"